# Password protect folder for Windows and Linux

Tags: dual-boot, encryption

I have a basic question of feasibility - feel free to delete / kill off if too broad or off-topic.

I dual-use Windows and Ubuntu because of various work purposes. I have some sensitive files where it would be best to restrict folder/file access a bit. It's not hide-from-the-NSA-secret, but hide-from-plain-access (job-applications and such). Is there a good way to encrypt/secure the folder and still be able to access it from Windows and Ubuntu with some convenience? Because of dual use, the files are not in a linux-formatted drive, so any advanced options there are out of play.

A gaffer-tape solution I could think of is to pack everything into an encrypted archive (7z or so) and unpack/repack as needed, but there might be a more elegant way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In case it is just a few files compression would work BUT compressed files can be copied to another location and then someone can try to bruteforce it at their own time.

Bitlocker and the Linux companion [dislocker](https://github.com/Aorimn/dislocker) will also work. We use that here to lock notebooks and USB sticks where the USB sticks can be opened and used with both Windows 7 and 10 and on Ubuntu. Just got to remember to lock the USB (or partition) when you go AFK.

Comment: Thanks! That's probably a bit more secure than I need. I am looking for an equivalent to the standard lockable office drawer. It could be opened with little motivation and a cheap screwdriver, but locking it counts as diligence. Nobody can just "happen upon" something sensitive. 


Could I do something like folder permissions that work under windows and linux, as with "foreign" home directories under win and linux?

Comment: Basically, forcing a password prompt to enter the folder (or appropriate it) could be enough. (Somebody chrooting from a USB is not a concern.) Just against somebody clicking around while I am AFK for a minute. 

(“Luck is my middle name," said Rincewind, indistinctly. "Mind you, my first name is Bad.”)

Comment: "Could I do something like folder permissions that work under windows and linux" Not really. "Basically, forcing a password prompt to enter the folder (or appropriate it) could be enough" On linux you could use the "root" user: own the file by root and nobody can touch it in Linux. Windows does not care about that though ;)